# POST de dados JSON pelo CURL

Tags: json, http, post, cmd

Estou começando a usar o JSON-SERVER, ainda não tenho muito conhecimento. Estou tentando fazer um POST de dados JSON com CURL no cmd do windows. Estou utilizando o seguinte codigo:

```
curl -d "{"nome":"usuario1", "idade":40, "sexo":"feminino"}" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/usuarios
```

Na janela que eu executo o código acima aparece este erro:

Error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Na janela do nó em que o servidor esta rodando aparece o seguinte erro:

```
POST /usuarios 400 2.150 ms - 1111 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Ja procurei mas ainda não encontrei como resolver esse erro

Comment: Mude de `"{"nome":"usuario1", "idade":40, "sexo":"feminino"}"` para `'{"nome":"usuario1", "idade":40, "sexo":"feminino"}'`, ou seja de `"` para `'` que envolve o json

Comment: Agora aparece esse erro na janela que eu executo o codigo:                                                 
curl: (3) Port number ended with ','
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39; in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError

Comment: (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done

Comment: (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\motad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Melhor atualizar o post, ao invés de usar os comentários para isso.

Comment: como assim? desculpa a pergunta mas ainda estou começando nessa parte de HTTP, teria como me explicar como fazer isso?

Comment: Ao final do seu post existe um link para editar o mesmo. Use-o para atualizar com as mensagens de erro e o que você fez.